# In Vue 2 how to have only 1st input type checkbox checked in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, vue-component

Thanks for having look I'm kinda stuck.Trying to figure out how to have first checkbox rendered checked by default.

Here is my JS the categories are coming in dynamically

```
Vue.component('category-filter', {
  template: '#category-filter-template',
  props: {
    appMounted: false,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      categories: {},
      checkedState: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleCheckboxClicked(e) {
      console.log({ e });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.appMounted = true;
    this.categories =jsContext.categories
  },
});
```

Here is my template I have choose to make styles inline to make component more reusable

```
<div
  class="filter-container--wrapper"
  style="
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5676a7;
    border-radius: 5px;
  "
>
  <div
    id="filter-item"
    style="padding: 15px"
    v-for="category in categories"
    :key="category.id"
  >
    <input
      id="category-name"
      type="checkbox"
      @click="handleCheckboxClicked($event)"
      :value="category.id"
      :checked="checkedState"
    />
    <label for="category-name">
      <span>\{{category.name}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialy define the value as checked by setting it when you setup the data for the model:

`this.categories = Array.from(jsContext.categories || []).map((v,i) => (v.checked = !i, v));`

Various issues:

- You should use a model instead of `:value`, then change the model to checked.
- Don't mutate props!
- If categories is an array then set it as array in data, not object.
- Is better to use computed props for the inline style, or if possible always put it in your CSS file or in `<style>`, you can scope it `#category-filter-template .filter-container--wrapper {}` if you don't want it conflicting.

```
<template id="category-filter-template">
  <div class="filter-container--wrapper" :style="wrapperStyle">
    <div
      id="filter-item"
      :style="itemStyle"
      v-for="category in categories"
      :key="category.id"
    >
      <input
        id="category-name"
        type="checkbox"
        v-model="category.checked"
        :checked="category.checked"
      />
      <label for="category-name">
        <span>\{{category.name}}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then your component:

```
Vue.component('category-filter', {
  template: '#category-filter-template',
  data() {
    return {
      categories: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    wrapperStyle () {
      return {
      'display': 'flex',
      'flex-wrap': 'wrap',
      '-webkit-box-pack': 'center',
      '-ms-flex-pack': 'center',
      'justify-content': 'center',
      'margin-bottom': ' 2rem',
      'color': '#fff',
      'background-color': ' #5676a7',
      'border-radius': ' 5px'
      }
    },
    itemStyle () {
      return {
        'padding': '15px'
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.categories = Array.from(jsContext.categories || []).map((v,i) => (v.checked = !i, v))
  },
})
```

See working online: https://playcode.io/847454/

Comment: @LawernceCherone Thanks so much Im new to Vue. So I could I put the styles in style tag in my html template file? would the scoped attribute apply here?

Comment: its better to put any styles in a CSS file(s) and import them with a link tag in head, later on when you port your code to use single file components structure you could put it in the style section. computed styles are really for if they are dynamic styles but its better then doing it inline in the template

Comment: I guess the computed styles would be best for me in this case. I hope you have a great holiday season thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the source of truth in your model, not in your rendering.

You should have something like

```
mounted() {
  this.categories[0].id=true;
}
```

however, it's not clear what the structure of categories is. Is it an array? If so, you should initialized it as an empty array instead of an object. Also, if you should probably be using `v-model` instead of `:value` so that changes in checked status are saved in the model. Finally, I'm not sure if you want the model to be linked to the `id` attribute. Probably there is another attribute that you want to bind.